# Build a texting app

Tags: android, sms, sendmessage

i am trying to build an app that send and receive sms . I know how to send the sms using smsManager ,then receive the sms and view in a Toast . but my problem is i want the sent sms and received sms to appear in my activity ,just like built in sms application,(conversation look )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you receive the SMS, i assume that you have written a `BroadcaseReceiver` that receive the intent associated with receeiving SMS.

In that receiver, all you have to do is to store the SMS (like in a database).

Then you add an `Activty` that show the messages stored by your receiver.

Comment: so i have to create a database and save my sms on it?? then my activity can access the data!

Comment: Yes. The point is to store the sms, you can use a database or whatever you feel like.